# How to calculate global sections on a complex curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let C be the complex curve $y^{2} = x^{8} - 1$ and $\sigma(x,y) = (\zeta x,y)$ be automorphism of order $r$ = 8, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $r$-th root of unity.
How to calculate basis of $H^{0}(K_{C})$?

I know that the answer is $\frac{dx}{y},\frac{xdx}{y},\frac{x^{2}dx}{y}$. I've tried to prove it by showing that every global section is a linear combinations of these, but failed.

Comment: Do you know the definition of Kahler differentials and how it is defined for an affine variety?

Comment: Also you do not say anything about the automorphism. Why is it there? Btw I feel lime the space of differentials should be bigger because genus should be 21 if you have a degree 8 smooth plane curve.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician, Sorry, I forgot to mention that the curve supposed to be in the projective plane. That's why the genus of the curve is actually 3.

Comment: Yes. That’s how I understood it. Is that $x^8$ suppose to be $x^4$? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula.   I could be wrong here and there’s a singulsrity I am missing.

Comment: If I understood correctly, there is an non ordinary singularity at a point (0:1:0), so we can't apply this formula.

Comment: Okay perfect -- that checks out now. Then the question is do you know how to compute differentials. This is the sort of stuff Vakil covers in his notes on his chapter about differentials

Comment: The dimension of $H^0(K_C)$ is equal to the genus $g=3$, so if you know that those 3 differentials are linearly independent, then you're done. Note that your question is actually solved by a more general result: given a hyperelliptic curve $y^2 = f(x)$ of genus $g$ in Weierstrass form, $\left\{\frac{dx}{y}, x \frac{dx}{y}, \ldots, x^{g-1} \frac{dx}{y}\right\}$ is a basis for the space of holomorphic differentials. I think this is proved somewhere in Miranda's book on Riemann surfaces

Comment: Or is your problem showing that these differentials are indeed holomorphic, i.e., have no poles?